# CSS - 100 height in a tablecell

Tags: html, css, tablecell

I have a table cell with various height.
I want to have 1 or more spans in the last cell with some requirements:

- height must be equal of the full row height, **most imortant**
- width must be equal to the spans. So exactly fit to the right and no whitespace on the left.

I can not find the solution.

The CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

table {
  width:100%;
}
td { border:1px solid blue; }
input {
    height:50px;
}
.buttons {
  width:1px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.button {
    padding:5px 20px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="I have height of 50px" /></td>
        <td class="buttons">
            <span class="button" title="I have width of 25px">+</span>
            <span class="button" title="I have width of 25px">+</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried position relative/absolute on the last td and a container for the buttons, but then it will fall outside the table
Ofcourse i tried height:100%, no difference

http://jsfiddle.net/70a6q5kz/3/

--edit
**Solution**
I found this solution:
Css:

```
table { height:100%; }
.buttons { height:100% }
```

Full solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/70a6q5kz/11/

Comment: which height must be equal to the full row height? if it's your buttons, then you need to add a `br`: http://jsfiddle.net/70a6q5kz/7/

Comment: Both buttons needs stay on 1 row and 100% height of the row

Comment: If you have a set height for your input, why not just give that height to your buttons, then you can use flex to centre the text: http://jsfiddle.net/70a6q5kz/9/

Comment: Because what is inside the first columns or how it is styled is not always the same. This must be an universal solution.

Comment: then don't use tables, it's not semantically correct anyway - tables should only be used for tabular data.  Also don't edit your question with a solution, post an answer - and you probably want to check your solution is cross browser friendly, when I have set a height like that in the past it breaks in ie

Comment: I`ll do that, thanks.
Works in IE, FF and chrome. I do need a table because it is for tabular data. It is for an editable grid, but the user can style the inputs, make the lineheight or fontsize larger. So the buttons need to grow with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with `flex`. You also need to remove the initial `padding` of the `td`s.

Check snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0; /* remove initial padding */
}

input {
  height: 50px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button {
  flex: auto;
  width: 25px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input value="I have height of 50px" /></td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttons">
        <span class="button" title="I have width of 25px">+</span>
        <span class="button" title="I have width of 25px">+</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css you could remove the padding from td, create the .button:last-of-type and insert a margin-right:-1px on it

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

table {
  width:100%;
}
td { 
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding: 0; /********************************/
 }
input {
    height:50px;
}
.buttons {
  width:1px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}
.button:last-of-type{ /*************************/
  margin-right:-1px;  /*************************/
}                     /*************************/
.button {
    padding:15px 20px;
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
}
```

The html can stay the same

Comment: How about the height? That is the main question

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution**
I found this as an possible solution. In simple words:
Css:

```
table { height:100%; }
.buttons { height:100% }
```

Full solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/70a6q5kz/11/
Works in IE 11, FF and chrome